# Bootstrap Carousel Transition Glitch/Bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm currently implementing a bootstrap carousel into my website. It has been implemented successfully but I am running into an issue where during each transition the image will halve in size and cause the entire page to move.

The problem can be found here: https://braydonburn.github.io/clean_endeavour/
Source files can be found here: https://github.com/braydonburn/clean_endeavour

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks, Braydon.

Edit:

I've added a minimum height to the container and pushed the changes to the site, the problem is still there but the entire container doesn't shrink anymore, only the inner carousel image.

Edit:

Issue was caused by the following in my css file:

```
.left {
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-right: 8%;
  width: 60%;
}

.right {
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-right: 8%;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: try giving min-height to the container

Comment: add height to .item

Comment: I've added a minimum height to the container and pushed the changes to the site, the problem is still there but the entire container doesn't shrink anymore, only the inner carousel image.